# Yii2 class Yii/web/UrlManager causes error

Tags: php, yii2, yii-url-manager

I have urlManager like this in web.php

```
        'urlManager' => 
    [
        //'class' => 'yii/web/UrlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enableStrictParsing' => false,
        'rules' => 
        [
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ],
    ],
```

I just wanna know, why if I uncomment  'class' => 'yii/web/UrlManager', will cause error when I run my website.

Thank You so much

Comment: What error does it cause specifically?

Answer (score 2):

Your `Class` path from

> Url manager

is not correct. `Yii` work with namespace and to use namespace always use backslash `\` instead of front slash `/`. So your code should be in following format:

```
 'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
```

Instead of

```
'class' => 'yii/web/UrlManager',
```

Answer (score 1):

UrlManager path is wrong. why because this should be like namespace.

```
yii/web/UrlManager
```

instead of this, try this.

```
yii\web\UrlManager
```

Note:- it's back slash not front slash.